# Why does `assoc` return nil for a plist?

Tags: association-lists, property-lists

I've got the following issue:

```
(setq testvar '(link (:type "http" :path "//pygments.org/docs" :format 
bracket :raw-link "http://pygments.org/docs" :application nil)))

(setq testvar (nth 1 testvar))
(assoc :path testvar) ;;nil --- why?
```

I can't get a value of any of this keys, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How about:  `(plist-get testvar :path)`  The doc-string for `assoc` appears to indicate it is designed to be used differently:  "*Return non-nil if KEY is `equal` to the car of an element of LIST.  The value is actually the first element of LIST whose car equals KEY.*"

Comment: Awesome! Please provide this as the answer.

Comment: What makes you think that `assoc` would act as you expect? What did `C-h f assoc` or `C-h S assoc` tell you about its behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the doc-string for `assoc`, it is used to:  "*Return non-nil if KEY is `equal` to the car of an element of LIST.  The value is actually the first element of LIST whose car equals KEY.*"  The manual contains a few examples:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Association-Lists.html

The function `plist-get` appears to be appropriate in this instance:  `(plist-get testvar :path)`.  The doc-string for said function is as follows:

```
Extract a value from a property list.
PLIST is a property list, which is a list of the form
(PROP1 VALUE1 PROP2 VALUE2...).  This function returns the value
corresponding to the given PROP, or nil if PROP is not one of the
properties on the list.  This function never signals an error.
```

Answer (score 3):

You've already received tips on what to use instead of `assoc`, but just to answer your original question: `assoc` expects a list of cons cells as input:

```
(setq testvar
      '((:type "http") (:path "//pygments.org/docs")
       (:format bracket) (:raw-link "http://pygments.org/docs")
       (:application nil)))

(assoc :path testvar)
==> (:path "//pygments.org/docs")
```

Note that when using symbols (or keywords, which are a special kind of symbols), it's more appropriate to use `assq`, because it uses `eq` for comparison, rather than `equal`.

Note also that you may think that `(:path "//pygments.org/docs")` isn't a cons cell, but it is. It's a cons cell with a list as second element:

```
(equal '(:path "//pygments.org/docs") '(:path . ("//pygments.org/docs")))
==> t
```